# My wordpress site has "https://" on it but when I go to Dashboard and click visit site, it removes the "https://"

Tags: redirect, security

We have an internal website that is accessible only if you have an office 365 employee logins. It's hosted on bluehost and we have activated the https feature of it. Our site is running on WordPress multisite and is secured with https access.

Now when I go to any site's dashboard, the Visit Site link on top of it redirects me to a page without the "https://".

Same thing goes when I create a new page or post, the permalink that is available to click also doesn't have the "http://" or only "http" and without the "s" on it.

I also created a redirect using [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) without https:// to https://
 but the site did not work (it gives me a 404 error).

The pages work with or without the https but chrome is saying that pages without is not secure. What are possible fix for this and why is this happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded [Really Simple SSL](https://really-simple-ssl.com/?ref=52&campaign=wpbeginner) and activate it. Now all the dashboard link leading to the site is now secured. Thanks!